# CE Image - output only the src value

Tags: ce-image

`{exp:ce_img:single}` or the like outputs `<img>` tags.

Is there a way in CE to make it only output the @src value only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different ways to go about this, but the most succinct is probably to use the [url_only=](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters#url_only) parameter:

```
{exp:ce_img:single src="{your_custom_field}" url_only="yes" width="200"}
```

You could also customize the output using the [output=](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters#output) parameter:

```
{exp:ce_img:single src="{your_custom_field}" output="{made}" width="200"}
```

Or use the [made variable](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/variables#made) in a [pair tag](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/basics#tag_pair) (like Max pointed out):

```
{exp:ce_img:pair src="{your_custom_field}" width="200"}{made}{/exp:ce_img:pair}
```

Comment: I don't know how I could have missed `url_only` in the documentation but thanks for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 3):

Use [:pair](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/basics#tag_pair) tag

```
{exp:ce_img:pair src="{your_custom_field}"}
<img src="{made}" alt="" width="{width}" height="{height}" />
{/exp:ce_img:pair}
```